# Transform and copy all properties of an object

Tags: java

I have a large monthly summary object with lots of fields. When creating a new one, I need to calculate the amount / percent diff for each field from the previous month, something like so:

```
public Summary addSummary(Summary current) {
   Summary previous = getPreviousSummary(getPreviousMonth();

   current.setPropertyA(NumUtil.getFormattedValue(current.getPropertyA(), previous.getPropertyA()));
   // repeat 80 more times

   ...
}
```

currently I'm doing it manually, which is tedious and super ugly, is there a way to loop through all the properties / set them after running them through a function?

I did some searching and BeanUtils can copy properties, but not transform them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Is `mapstruct` an option? It has some data type conversion and formatting support. https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#datatype-conversions

Comment: Are all the properties the same type?

Comment: You have no problem with writing 80 getter/setter pairs for your 80 properties, but a problem writing 80 lines of "format value"? Why?

Comment: I use lombok so the class files are much cleaner :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use *reflection* to solve your problem. As I don't know actually what you're gonna get and set from those two objects, I am giving a minimal example to show what you can do in this case.

You can get all the declared fields in your `Summary` class as follows:

```
Field[] arrayOfFields = Summary.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

As you have all the fields of the class summary, you can iterate through each field and do the get and set easily for different objects of that class as follows. Remember to set `field.setAccessible(true)` if the fields are private inside the class:

```
for (Field field: arrayOfFields) {
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (field.getType() == Double.class) {
            Double prevVal = field.get(previous);
            Double currentVal = field.get(current);
            //do calculation and store to someval
            field.set(resultSummary, someval);
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Well, you may need to check all type of classes that your class `Summary` has and do the get and set according to that type. Please keep in mind that you cannot use primitive type fields for this `if` condition check as they are not Class. So, you may need to convert the *primitive* type variables in the `summary` class to corresponding Object Class. Like `double` to `Double` etc.

The `field.get(Object obj)` method gets the value for the field in the Object `obj`. Similarly, `field.set(Object obj, Object value)` sets the Object `value` to the field in the Object `obj`

With this approach you can achieve the goal easily with less hassle and dynamic coding.